# Gabor filter and hough transform

Tags: hough-transform, gabor-filter

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to detect lanes, I use gabor filter in order to detect edges and line then apply hough transform but I've a problem as it gives exception when trying to either do canny detection or houghline directly 
I want to know what is the output of Gabor filter is it complex values ? and how to work with the complex values in opencv?
here is a part of my code :

```
int kernel_size = 9;
double sig = 2, th = 0, lm =10, gm =1, ps = CV_PI/4;
cv::Mat kernel =    cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
cv::filter2D(src_f, src_f, CV_32F, kernel);
imshow("kernel",kernel);

Mat viz;
src_f.convertTo(viz,CV_8U,1.0/255.0);    
imshow("d",viz);
imshow("Result", src_f);

std::vector<float> uniquev = unique(src_f, true);
int TotalPixel = uniquev.size();
int nTotalThresholdPixel = TotalPixel * 2.5/100;
float thresholdValue = uniquev[nTotalThresholdPixel-1];
int i = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < MaxHeight; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < MaxWidth; col++)
    {

        if(src_f.at<float>(row, col) <thresholdValue )
            {src_f.at<float>(row, col)  =0;}

    }
}

Mat imgContours;
double thresh = 255; 

try{
    Canny(src_f,imgContours,0.6*thresh, thresh); 
    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    HoughLines(src_f,lines,1,CV_PI/180,130);
    Mat imgOutput;
    cvtColor( src_f, imgOutput, CV_GRAY2BGR );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float theta = lines[i][1];
        float rho = lines[i][0];
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        Point pt1(cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)),cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)));
        Point pt2(cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b)),
        cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a)));
        line( src_f, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8 );
    }
}
catch(exception e ){

}
```

I think I've a problem in the output of gabor filter itself as it is float and -ve numbers

I got the exception here either in

```
          Canny(src_f,imgContours,0.6*thresh, thresh);
```

or in if commented Canny

```
           HoughLines(src_f,lines,1,CV_PI/180,130);
```

Comment: What's the exception's type, message & stacktrace?

Comment: {_Mywhat=0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> _Mydofree=false } std::exception

Comment: I want to know how to work in the image after gabor filter as far as I know it output a complex number imaginary and real part so how should I work with them ?